# Using XAPSignTool with a password-less PFX certificate to sign a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, code-signing

I have a PFX certificate with an empty password. I need to use to to sign a XAP file (Windows Phone 8 binary).

The script to do this (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\BuildMDILXap.ps1) that runs XAPSignTool excepts a password.

Not providing password for this script does not execute the signing. So I tried editing this script so it calls XAPSignTool without the /p parameter but it did not work

```
XAPSignTool failed for the xap with error:( 1 )
```

If I provide an empty password `$Arguments += "/p "` I get

```
SignTool Error: The specified PFX password is not correct.
XAPSignTool failed for the xap with error:( 1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to make the tools work with a certificate with an empty password, so I changed the password on the certificate using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out tmpmycert.pem -nodes

openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert2.pfx -in tmpmycert.pem

del tmpmycert.pem
```